# Can reconfigurable ideas be applied to software system development?

Tags: language-agnostic, achievements

Reconfigurable ideas in hardware programming-especially FPGAs have a lot of application scenarios.

> Definition of reconfigurable computing:
>
> Reconfigurable computing is also called configurable computing,
>   reprogrammable computing or custom computing.
>
> As a computing model in the space-time domain, it can not only use the
>   reconfigurable devices to customize dedicated computing components in
>   design and implementation,  but also reuse computing resources to
>   achieve multiple different computing tasks.  Therefore, it acts as a
>   bridge between hardware and software, and bridges the gap in
>   performance and flexibility between the two.

But why don't anyone try it in software?

I wonder how difficult it is to apply reconfigurable ideas to software system development?

If there is no difficulty, why no one does it?

If it ’s difficult, please help guide me.

Comment: If there are similar companies or products that apply reconfigurable ideas to software system development, please tell me, thank you

Comment: `reuse computing resources to achieve multiple different computing tasks` - Do you not consider that a [Turing machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_machine) which is comparable to a  computer. Remember that IBM started with making mechanical machines that did just one thing, such as sorting a deck of punched cards - [IBM card sorter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_card_sorter). Then the started selling computers because the software could be crated to solve `multiple different computing tasks`.